# How did Chebyshev prove this weaker form of Rosser's theorem?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, reference-request, prime-numbers

I have come to know of an elementary proof, by Chebyshev, that there exists a real $\alpha<1$ such that $$ p_n > \alpha n \log n, $$ where $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime. As I am failing to find it online, I hope someone can provide a link to it or reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Google search for
"chebyshev function prime number theorem"
came up with,
among others,
this:
https://www.math.columbia.edu/~nsnyder/tutorial/lecture56.pdf

Section 3 has a proof of
 Chebyshev’s Theorem.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know it involved the $\psi$ function.